# Is it possible to run a delayed job immediately but still asynchronously?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, delayed-job

We are using [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to run tasks in the background because they could take a while, and also because if an error is thrown, we still want the web request to succeed.

The issue is, sometimes the job could be really big (changing hundreds or thousands of database rows) and sometimes it could be really small (like 5 db rows). In the case of the small ones, we'd still like to have it run as a delayed job so that the error handling can work the same way, but we'd love to not have to wait roughly 5 seconds for DJ to pick up the job.

Is there a way to queue the job so it runs in the background, but then immediately run it so we don't have to wait for the worker to execute 5 seconds later?

**Edit:** Yes, this is Ruby on Rails :-)

Answer (score 1):

Delayed Job polls the database for new dj records at a set interval. You can reconfigure this interval in an initializer:

```
# config/delayed_job.rb
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 2 # or 1 if you're feeling wild.
```

This will affect DJ globally.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SomeJob.set(
    wait: 0,
    queue: "queue_name",
  ).perform_later
```